# Healthcheck command and Environment variables to ECS Task definition Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have a cloudformation template YAML to create an ECS task definition, Can anybody help me how can i pass a command to the HealthCheck property of containerdefinition.

Also I have a Environment variable JAVA_OPTS to be set to some values like -Xmx..

i am struggling to pass those values correctly in the yaml. if anybody has done that please help.

Comment: Can you share your template, or its relevant parts?

Comment: HealthCheck:Command: -echo "hi" Retries: "2" StartPeriod: "30" Interval:"30" TimeOut: "30" In thi I am struggling with the Command Property, continuosly getting an error Command should be list of strings & for Environment: -Name:JAVA_OPTS -value:Xms256m